# Evaluation of OptionValue[]

Tags: evaluation, options

I have a function that takes an `OptionsPattern` and I want to access several options, say `a`, and `b`. This works great:

```
f1[OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{},
   {OptionValue[a],OptionValue[b]}
  ];
Options[f1] = {a -> 1, b -> 2};
```

Calling `f1[]` returns `{1,2}` as expected. The problem is that I don't know in advance which options I'll want to access. So I thought about trying this:

```
f2[OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{list},
   list={a,b};
   OptionValue /@ list
  ];
Options[f2] = {a -> 1, b -> 2};
```

`f2` doesn't work, and neither do `f3`:

```
f3[OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{},
   OptionValue /@ {a,b}
  ];
```

They both return `{OptionValue[a], OptionValue[b]}`. However, this ***does*** work:

```
f4[OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{},
   OptionValue[#]& /@ {a,b}
  ];
```

> **Question**:  Why on earth do `f2,f3` not work, while `f4` does, and what is the difference between `f4` and `f3` anyhow?

*PS*
 These also these don't work:

```
f5[OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{},
  Evaluate[OptionValue /@ {a, b}]
  ];

f6[OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{},
  OptionValue /@ Evaluate[{a, b}]
  ];
```

Comment: Try also `f7[OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{}, OptionValue@{a, b}];`:)

Comment: @belisarius great!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### A guess

My guess is that you have just run into the details of `OptionValue` implementation, which are also responsible for its "magical" behavior. `OptionValue` has to somehow know which function it is in, and tracing the execution of `f4[]` shows that apparently the following expansion is happening before any evaluation is attempted for the r.h.s.:

```
OptionValue[#]& -> OptionValue[f4,{},#]&
```

Now, it seems like this (lexical) substitution is triggered when `OptionValue[something]` is found somewhere on the r.h.s., but not when `OptionValue` appears as a symbol without arguments. Note that such replacement can not be a part of normal evaluation, but rather looks like a macro-like expansion, based on the lexical analysis of the code on the r.h.s.

Consider this example

```
d[a -> 8] /. d[OptionsPattern[]] :> HoldComplete@OptionValue[a]
(* HoldComplete[OptionValue[d, {a -> 8}, a]] *)
```

Now, `HoldComplete` holds all kinds of dynamic evaluation of the right hand side. However, `OptionValue` was expanded.

When you are using the magic couple in a way that `OptionsPattern` has no head, the expansion results in an empty list `{}` as `OptionValue`'s first argument.

```
d[a -> 8] /. OptionsPattern[] :> HoldComplete@OptionValue[a]
(* d[HoldComplete[OptionValue[{}, {a -> 8}, a]]] *)
```

It seems like the `OptionsPattern` search is done `Heads->False` and at levels 0 and 1 only. The expansion doesn't happen for lhs such as `OptionsPattern[][]` or `f[g[OptionsPattern[]]`. This might be to ensure there is either no or a single head enclosing all the `OptionsPattern`.

#### An illustration

Here is some code to mimic this behavior:

```
Module[{tried},
  Unprotect[SetDelayed];
  SetDelayed[
     f_[args___, optpt : OptionsPattern[]], rhs_
  ] /;!FreeQ[Unevaluated[rhs], optionValue[_]]:=
  Block[{tried = True},
     f[args, optpt] :=
        Unevaluated[rhs] /. optionValue[s_] :> optionValue[f, {optpt}, s]
  ] /; ! TrueQ[tried];
  Protect[SetDelayed];
]
```

**NOTE!!** - this redefines `SetDelayed`(the idea taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335897/mathematica-how-is-optionvalue-implemented/5336802#5336802)). So now:

```
f8[OptionsPattern[]]:=Block[{},optionValue[#]&/@{a,b}];
f8[]

(* {optionValue[f8,{},a],optionValue[f8,{},b]} *)

f9[OptionsPattern[]]:=Block[{},optionValue/@{a,b}];
f9[]

(* {optionValue[a],optionValue[b]}  *)
```

It remains now to define `optionValue[f_,opts_List,name_]` to make this emulation to work.

```
Unprotect[SetDelayed];
Clear[SetDelayed];
Protect[SetDelayed]
```

#### Remarks

I wouldn't call this behavior consistent, but this is almost certainly a consequence of the internal mechanism (implementation) for the `OptionsPattern` - `OptionValue` construct. Whether it is at all possible to make this "magic" fully work in all cases, is IMO a good question.

As to the reason why this does not work for other cases, it looks like `OptionValue` is dynamically - scoped, in some sense. Only its long (non-magical) form has enough information about the calling function and passed options, to work. At run-time, the short form  is evaluated(since the expansion into a long form did not happen), and this short form simply evaluates to itself.

Comment: My answer didn't add much to this, +1

Comment: @Rojo Thanks for the upvote. You'll beat me to it next time :). I added some code to further illustrate things. Please feel free to add to this answer, I think you had some things I don't (local rules, for one).

Comment: Edited. Feel free to roll back

Comment: @Rojo Thanks! Looks pretty good to me.

Comment: So it looks like this cannot be implemented with standard Mathematica constructs (`Stack`?). We couldn't make our own OptionValue implementation. Right?

Comment: @Szabolcs I think we can, but it won't work *exactly* as `OptionValue` - but may be close enough to do what you want. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5336802/565518) is one possible (but simplistic) implementation. I think `Stack` can be used, too. The real `OptionValue` expands semi-lexically / semi-dynamically at run-time, and surely that was a special case added to the main evaluator, so one probably can't implement that *exact* behavior in a robust way on the top level, but it must be possible to mimic the main part (get the name of the caller) reasonably well with `Stack`.

Comment: This is why I asked: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96420/12

Answer (score 0):

The practical upshot of Leonid's answer seems to be that you can't Map the bare symbol OptionValue but must use an explicit Function form.

So this works:

```
ClearAll[f1];
Options[f1] = {a -> 1, b -> 2};
f1[OptionsPattern[]] := {OptionValue[a], OptionValue[b]}
```

And, using Map, so does this:

```
ClearAll[f2];
Options[f2] = {a -> 1, b -> 2};
f2[OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[#] & /@ {a, b}
```

Comment: Well, I stated this in my question.