# How to find the name of the current function?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, debugging, coding-style

I would like to know the name of the current function from within that function.  For example, consider the following code

```
myFunction[args___] :=
  Module[{},
    checkArgs[args,"myFunction"];
    someCode[]
  ];
```

where `checkArgs` is used in several functions which have the same types of arguments and reports an error message which includes the name of the function it was called from.  I would like to call `checkArgs` without having to give it the name of the function.

The evaluation stack, obtained using `Stack`, I believe does not contain this information unless called from within a `StackComplete`, and this is generally not the case in normal use of the function.

I appreciate that "the current function" is not necessarily a well-defined concept in *Mathematica*, since you can have nested function definitions, and a function is just a rule definition anyway.  However, the options management system uses this concept.  If I have `OptionsPattern` in the function definition, I can call `OptionValue`, and something knows to look in `Options[myFunction]` to find the information about the options.  So could whatever this mechanism is using be accessed?  Is there a way to get the current function from the options system?

The best solution I have come up with is this:

```
(fn:myFunction)[args___] :=
  Module[{},
    checkArgs[args,fn];
    someCode[]
  ];
```

which avoids having to pass in the function name explicitly, but is still quite ugly.

Comment: Apart from being ugly, what shortcomings does your workaround solution have? I'm not sure that Leonid's answer is not an overkill if the only real difference is uglyness. Nevertheless, would be nice to have a built-in solution a la `OptionValue`.

Comment: [A related thread.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68823)

Answer (score 16):

#### Custom assignement operators

Not quite what you asked for, but (as we already discussed recently), you can use custom assignment operators to define some variable that would have the value set to the name of your function inside its body. Here is a possibility:

```
ClearAll[def];
SetAttributes[def, HoldAll];
def /: SetDelayed[def[f_[args___]], rhs_] :=
   f[args] := Block[{$inFunction = f}, rhs];
Protect[def];
```

The above assignment operator is based on dynamic scoping. In case you want to bind lexically, you can do a similar thing, which in this case becomes a macro:

```
ClearAll[deflex];
SetAttributes[deflex, HoldAll];
deflex /: SetDelayed[deflex[f_[args___]], rhs_] :=
   Hold[rhs] /. HoldPattern[currentFunction] :> 
       f /. Hold[code_] :> SetDelayed @@ Hold[f[args], code];
Protect[deflex]
```

In contrast to `def`, the `deflex` operator does not wrap `Block[{$inFunction = f}, ...]` around the body of your function, but rather replaces all literal occurrences of `currentFunction` in the body of your function with `f`, before making a definition.

#### Example

The above form allows for a natural-looking code:

```
def @ myFunction[args___] :=
   Module[{}, checkArgs[args, $inFunction]]
```

so that you just have to add `def @` to the usual definition. Here is the generated defintion:

```
?myFunction
```

> ```
> Global`myFunction
> myFunction[args___]:=
>     Block[{$inFunction=myFunction},Module[{},checkArgs[args,$inFunction]]]
> ```

And here is a test:

```
myFunction[1,2,3]

(* checkArgs[1,2,3,myFunction] *)
```

You can do a similar thing with `deflex`:

```
ClearAll[mySecondFunction];
deflex @ mySecondFunction[args___] :=
   Module[{}, checkArgs[args, currentFunction]]
```

although the generated definition will be different:

```
?mySecondFunction
```

> ```
> Global`mySecondFunction
> mySecondFunction[args___]:=Module[{},checkArgs[args,mySecondFunction]]
> ```

In this case, both definitions efectively result in a similar run-time behavior, but there can be situations where this will not be the case.

#### How it works

Per request, let's break down the way how these operators work. I will consider `deflex` only, as a more complex one.

The first observation which follows directly from the definition of `deflex` is that it works at definition-time. Consider a simplified one:

```
ClearAll[deftest];
SetAttributes[deftest, HoldAll];
deftest /: SetDelayed[deftest[f_[args___]], rhs_] := {Hold[f[args], Hold[rhs]]}
```

Let's see what happens when we use it:

```
deftest @ f[x_, y_] := x + y

(* {Hold[f[x_, y_], Hold[x + y]]} *)
```

You can see that no global rules were created for the symbol `f`:

```
DownValues[f]

(* {} *)
```

because the `UpValue` for `deftest` has completely overridden how `SetDelayed` works on `deftest[f_[args___]]` (in this particular case, `deftest[f[x_,y_]]`. So using this `UpValue`, we get the control from `SetDelayed` when it executes on any l.h.s. of the form `deftest[func_[x___]]`, and can then do with the l.h.s. and r.h.s. whatever we want.

Now consider the definition again:

```
ClearAll[mySecondFunction];
deflex @ mySecondFunction[args___] := 
  Module[{}, checkArgs[args, currentFunction]]
```

Let's clear the definition again first:

```
 ClearAll[mySecondFunction]
```

Here are the steps that the execution goes through:

1. Grab the r.h.s. of the definition and wrap it into `Hold`:

   ```
   step1 = Hold[Module[{}, checkArgs[args, currentFunction]]]

   (* Hold[Module[{}, checkArgs[args, currentFunction]]] *)
   ```
2. Replace all occurrences of the symbol `currentFunction` with the actual symbol to which we assign the definition (`DownValue`) - we know it since we have destructured the l.h.s. into pattern variables `f` and `args`:

   ```
   step2 = step1 /. HoldPattern[currentFunction] :> mySecondFunction

   (* Hold[Module[{}, checkArgs[args, mySecondFunction]]] *)
   ```
3. Now I will introduce an additional step to clarify what is going on: instead of using `SetDelayed` on the last step, let's first use `RuleDelayed`, which is very similar except it will not create a global rule but rather form a local rule. And also, let's first do it in a naive way, just using `RuleDalayed` directly:

   ```
   step3 = step2 /. Hold[code_] :> 
      RuleDelayed[mySecondFunction[args___], code]

   (* mySecondFunction[args$___] :> Module[{}, checkArgs[args, mySecondFunction]] *)
   ```

   The idiom that was used here is called [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression/1937#1937) on this site. The idea behind it is to inject some unevaluated pieces of code into larger expressions - see the link for an example, and you can see more example by [doing the search](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22injector%20pattern%22)

   So basically, we have assembled the final definition at this step, where the l.h.s. has been unchanged, but in the r.h.s. we have already replaced the symbol `currentFunction` by the actual head of the function being defined.

   There are only two differences w.r.t. the original code:

   a. We used `RuleDelayed` instead of `SetDelayed` to illustrate what we get back (since `SetDelayed` would've just created this very rule as a global one and return back `Null`)

   b. We still have a problem: if you look carefully at the result, we got the arguments in the pattern renamed, on the l.h.s.: `args$___`, while kept as they are, on the r.h.s. (`args`). This is not what we want, since such a rule will not work - we want the pattern variable to match the r.h.s.

   To do that, we have to fool the built-in variable renaming mechanism, which uses renaming to protect the inner lexical scoping constructs. The general ways to do that were described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia/20776#20776). One of the simplest ways is to replace `innerScopingConstruct[args]` with `innerScopingConstruct @@ Hold[args]` (see the mentioned link for explanations). So the correct third step would've been:

   ```
   step3Correct = step2 /. Hold[code_] :> 
      RuleDelayed @@ Hold[mySecondFunction[args___], code]

   (* mySecondFunction[args___] :> Module[{}, checkArgs[args, mySecondFunction]] *)
   ```

   where now no renaming has taken place and the pattern `arg___` on the l.h.s. matches the use of `arg` on the r.h.s.

What remains is to simply replace `RuleDelayed` by `SetDelayed`, and that would create a new / corrected global rule / definition, and attach it to `mySecondFunction` as a `DownValue`.

So basically, what `deflex` is doing is this:

- Intercepts the original call of `SetDelayed` on the l.h.s. of the form `deflex[func_[x___]]`
- Transforms the r.h.s. of that original definition by replacing all occurrences of symbol `currentFunction` with the actual value of `func`, while keeping the code held
- Forms a new definition and calls `SetDelayed` again, but this time directly on the l.h.s. without prepending `deflex` to it - thus allowing `SetDelayed` to execute "normally" on the modified definition and create a global rule.

So `deflex` really works somewhat similar to decorators in Python, since we end up with a modified definition. in fact, [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155567/permanently-extending-the-behaviour-of-functions-like-decorators/155578#155578) I have used a `deflex` - like construct to implement decorators, in exactly the same way.

#### Limitations

Note that this form of `def` (or `deflex`) can not handle definitions of this type:

```
def @ myFunction[args___] /; Length[{args}] > 1 :=
   Module[{}, checkArgs[args, $inFunction]]
```

but can handle a similar one like this:

```
def @ myFunction[args___] :=
   Module[{}, checkArgs[args, $inFunction]] /; Length[{args}] > 1
```

Comment: A bit OT, but I always wondered: How does the magic behind `OptionValue` work?

Comment: @sebhofer The best I can tell at the moment is what is described in my answer to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18674/evaluation-of-optionvalue).

Comment: Both solutions look amazing! IMO the later produces a more concise result; the former solution is brilliant in conception, the later one I really am not sure how it works; pure magic as far as I'm concerned. I'm really happy I saw these; they made my day

Comment: @yosimitsukodanuri Well, they are similar, except the latter one processes the code of the body of the function, adding the function name at definition time, while the former wraps the body in `Block`,  making a special variable available at run-time. In some cases, either one can be used, in others one might be preferable. In any case, glad you find them useful.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin I get how the `Block` one works; I hope I'll understand the `RuleDelayed` within the month; brilliant! thank you

Comment: After posting this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218386/in-over-my-head-in-trying-to-create-a-debugger I spent another 1-2 hours breaking down deflex & pondering how it works, without success. I'm especially stumped by precedence issues & in places can't even work out what happens first. Since it uses of a number of advanced ideas it would be a wonderful candidate for a step by step breakdown: I'm sure many would benefit from being able to do similar things. Would you be willing to answer if I posted a specific "How does @LeonidShifrin's code work?" question?

Comment: @JulianMoore Yep, I can do that. Unfortunately I don't have the time right now to answer your question on a debugger, since that would require a few hours to try things out, which I currently don't have - but I have "marked" that question for myself as something to look into when I get a moment. But the narrow one about `deflex` I surely can answer. Not sure it is best to have a separate question though - I can simply extend the answer above with the "how it works" section - this will probably be better.

Comment: @JulianMoore All right, I did my best to explain. I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: I will read the details with great interest and care... It did seem to require quite a lot of details, thanks for the time spent. Contributions to the "debugger" as and when time permits :)

Comment: @JulianMoore You are welcome. Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you mean to omit the Module[...] in step 1? Or you meant to omit from the example definition?

Comment: @JulianMoore Yes, I omitted the `Module`, since it doesn't play any role in that example, and was used simply to add a bit more meat and mimic more complex cases for the r.h.s. But you are right, it should be there for consistency, I will add it.

Comment: OK, thanks, just wanted to be sure

Answer (score 13):

If a current evaluation rule contains/uses `OptionsPattern[]` then you can abuse the fact that `OptionName[a]` is replaced by `OptionName[functionName, {}, a]`.

```
foo[OptionsPattern[]] := Hold[OptionValue[whatever]][[1, 1]]

(*DownValue: HoldPattern[foo[OptionsPattern[]]] :> Hold[OptionValue[whatever]][[1, 1]] *)
```

```
foo[]
```

> foo

Comment: Oh, that's a neat trick! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit yep, it is interesting

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can exploit `OptionValue` for this purpose, but of course this is not the answer you are looking for:

```
ClearAll[myFunction, checkArgs, someCode];
Options[myFunction] = {"Name" -> myFunction};
myFunction[arg_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{},
   checkArgs[arg, OptionValue@"Name"];
   someCode[];
   ];
```

Downside is that you have to maintain options. Also, you cannot really prevent something passing on a fake `"Name"->otherFunction` argument to your function. If all your functions have a `"Name"` option then at least you don't have to make the `checkArgs` call function-specific.

Of course you can use `"$$ObscureOptionUserShouldNotMeddleWith643x84"` instead of `"Name"`.