# What does f_[whoCalled]^:=f really mean?

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, symbolic, core-language, upvalues

I came across the following post by John Doty in [this Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/sQ_U6FJWJT4):

> On Friday, January 11, 2013 8:23:16 PM UTC-7, amzoti wrote:
>
> > It is clear the Mathematica uses Lisp as one of the example programming paradigms it pulls from and I have a general question
> >     regarding this.
>
> Perhaps not as much as you think. Mathematica is fundamentally a term
>   rewriting system, a more general concept than the lambda calculus
>   behind Lisp. To be sure, the easiest thing to express as term
>   rewriting is the replacement of a function invocation by its body (as
>   in the lambda calculus), but Mathematica can do more complex things,
>   some rather strange from the lambda calculus point of view. Consider
>
> ```
> f_[whoCalled]^:=f
> Sin[whoCalled]
> ```
>
> which yields
>
> > ```
> > Sin
> > ```
>
> Very alien to Lisp!

I tried out the same code, and it does indeed return `Sin` for `Sin[whoCalled]`.  But for `Plus[whoCalled]` it returns `whoCalled`.

Can someone please explain that little snippet of code, and why it sometimes returns the name of the caller and sometimes the symbol `whoCalled`?  And what does the construct `^:=` actually do?

**EDIT**

Having grokked around for a while, I notice something.  When a function has the `Flat` attribute, the output is `whocalled`; when it does not, the output is the function name.  So, for instance `Map[whoCalled]` returns `Map` but `Times[whoCalled]` returns `whoCalled`.

I have no idea if this is indeed the reason, but it's just something I have noticed.

Comment: For `^:=` check the Documentation on [UpSetDelayed](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSetDelayed.html)

Comment: The only thing I know is that the attribute isn't the reason, try `Attributes@plus = Attributes@Plus; plus@whoCalled`. BTW, this special upvalue is really interesting, it even breaks `UpValues` and `Unset` and `Break`!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the reason, at least primarily, that it works differently for [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html) is the following from its documentation:

> - Unlike other functions, Plus applies built-in rules before user-defined ones.

It may seem a little obscure, because perhaps we don't know all the rules, but these two are mentioned explicitly:

> - Plus[] is taken to be 0.
> - Plus[x] is x.

[`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html) is similar.

According to these rules, `Plus[whoCalled]` and `Times[whoCalled]` evaluate to `whoCalled` before the rule for `whoCalled` is applied.

The behavior does not have to do with a symbol having the `Flat` attribute per se, as can been seen in this example:

```
SetAttributes[g, Flat]
g[whoCalled]
(*  g  *)
```

*Edit update*: I had forgotten to address what [`UpSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSetDelayed.html) (`^:=`) actually does.  The principal explanations can be found in the tutorial [Associating Definitions with Different Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AssociatingDefinitionsWithDifferentSymbols.html) and its related tutorials.  What the definition does in this case is to create an up-value for the symbol `whoCalled`, which is a rule for rewriting an expression, namely,

```
{HoldPattern[f_[whoCalled]] :> f}
```

This rule replaces an expression of the form `h[whoCalled]` by its head `h`.  In the pattern, `f_` causes `f` to represent the head of the expression, which is the return value on the right-hand side.
*End edit*

---

[Kuba's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68823/what-does-f-whocalled-f-really-mean#comment190224_68825), showing `Plus[whoCalled]` returning `If` in his variant of `whoCalled`, requires some explanation in light of the above.  We can get a peak at what's going on in the following tweak of Kuba's definition:

```
f_[x___, whoCalled, y___] ^:= (Print[HoldComplete[f[x, whoCalled, y]]]; f);

Plus[whoCalled]

(*
  HoldComplete[
   If[False, whoCalled, 
    With[{OutputSizeLimit`Dump`boxes$ = 
       Block[{$RecursionLimit = Typeset`$RecursionLimit}, 
        MakeBoxes[whoCalled, StandardForm]]}, 
     OutputSizeLimit`Dump`loadSizeCountRules[]; 
     If[TrueQ[BoxForm`SizeCount[OutputSizeLimit`Dump`boxes$, 1048576]], 
      OutputSizeLimit`Dump`boxes$, 
      OutputSizeLimit`Dump`encapsulateOutput[
       whoCalled, $Line, $SessionID, 5]]], whoCalled]]
*)

(*  If  *)
```

So it's a side effect of the definition on some typesetting (output formatting).
To clarify, the internal code `If[...]` has a form that accidentally matches the definition of `whoCalled`:

```
If[x1, whoCalled, y1, y2]
```

with `x1 = False`, `y1 = With[]`, and `y2 = whoCalled`, which symbol appears as both the second and fourth arguments to `If`.

Indeed the definition wreaks havoc here and there throughout the system:

```
UpValues[whoCalled]

(*  UpValues  *)

? whoCalled
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Definition not cleared:

```
Clear[whoCalled]

(*  Clear  *)
```

You can use a string to clear the definition:

```
ClearAll["whoCalled"]
```

---

The question is clearly just a toy for exploring how *Mathematica* evaluates expressions. If for some reason one wants to override functions in this indirect way, it might be good to spend some time thinking about which heads `f` would be safe to override.  I wonder if any `` System` `` heads are safe.  Clearly core programming ones like `If` are not.  One could write a function to verify a head is safe and guard against evaluating `whoCalled` with unsafe `f` like this:

```
ClearAll["whoCalled"]
(*safeHeadQ[h_] := Context[b] === "Global`";  (* more conservative alternative *) *)
safeHeadQ[h_] := MatchQ[h, Except[If]];       (* minimal for the OP example *)
f_[x___, whoCalled, y___] /; safeHeadQ[f] ^:= f;
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on `Clear@a; a /: b_[c__, a[d_]] := a[b[c, d]]; {x, a[1]}`?

Comment: There's a weird thing happening with a mysterious `If`. `In[9]:= ClearAll@a; a /: b_[c__, a[d_]] := a[Print[{b, {c}, d}]; b[c, d]]; {x, a[1]}

During evaluation of In[9]:= {List,{x},1}

During evaluation of In[9]:= {If,{False,a[{x,1}],a[{x,1}]},{x,1}}

Out[9]= a[a[{x, 1}]]`

Comment: If we give `If` a `HoldAll` attribute, we can see it's coming from formatting functions I believe. ``ClearAll@a; a /: b_[c__, a[d_]] := 
 a[Print[Hold@{b, {c}, d}]; b[c, d]]; {x, a[1]}

During evaluation of In[11]:= Hold[{List,{x},1}]

During evaluation of In[11]:= Hold[{If,{!MemberQ[$BoxForms,StandardForm]||MatchQ[HoldComplete[a[{x,1}]],_[OutputSizeLimit`Dump`$unlimitedTextPattern]]||MatchQ[HoldComplete[a[{x,1}]], <<OMITTED FOR SPACE>>},{x,1}}]

Out[12]= a[{x, 1}]``

Comment: @xzczd (I forgot to tag you).

Comment: @xzczd It seems to be the same thing. Try something like a /: mem : b_[c__, a[d_]] /; (Print[HoldComplete[mem]]; True) := a[b[c, d]];`, which is basically the same thing as I did for Kuba's.  Basic the def. is applied once to generate `a[{x, 1}]` and then again, when the internal code accidentally matches the definition in formatting the output boxes.  Note the code if of the form `If[t, e1, e2, a[{x , 1}]`, where `e1` is also `a[{x, 1}]` but is matched in `c__`.

Comment: Didn't get this the first time: http://i.stack.imgur.com/94zsb.png -- ah, figured it out: the extra `HoldComplete[ToString[whoCalled]]` etc. are from the floating popup info.  Note having the `whoCalled` def. around messes up the Preferences dialog window!

Comment: @xzczd Also note, running ./MathKernel from terminal, `{x, a[1]}` appears like you would expect. ``In[2]:= Clear@a; a /: b_[c__, a[d_]] := a[b[c, d]]; {x, a[1]}                   

Out[2]= a[{x, 1}]``

Answer (score 3):

The difference in behaviour seem to be because `Plus` expects more than one argument.

```
f_[whoCalled] ^:= f
Sin[whoCalled]
Plus[whoCalled]
Minus[whoCalled]
MadeUp[whoCalled]

(* Sin
   whoCalled
   Minus
   MadeUp *)

f_[whoCalled, youCalled] ^:= f
Plus[whoCalled, youCalled]

(* Plus *)
```

Comment: I thought about that.  But I noticed that `If[whoCalled]` returned `If`.

Comment: Your example lead me to that: `f_[___, whoCalled, ___] ^:= f;
Plus[whoCalled]` --> `If` O_o

Comment: Lol, that's weird.

Comment: It also seems to be related to FE-Kernel communication because using only Kernel it returns `whoCalled`.

Comment: @Kuba You're rewriting history: http://youtu.be/tbJwwJ33TEI?t=17s