# Determining function name from within function

Tags: functions

Is it possible in Mathematica to have function recognize its name? Say FunFunction[blah blah blah

];

Is there a way, while still inside the function, for the function to recognize its own name?

Comment: As far as I know, no. You could determine it at runtime via `Stack` maybe.

Comment: A fuller example would be helpful, as there is more than one kind of function in *Mathematica*.  For instance, if you are writing the function yourself, you could simply type it yourself: `f[x_] := (Print["My name is ", f]; x^2)`

Comment: One could write the function `call : f[x_] := (Print["Hi! You called ", HoldForm[call]]; x^2)` and then `f[4]`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I am trying to avoid having to type the function name twice, for no real reason other than neatness. A print statement really doesn't do the trick, but to help clear up the question lets say I wanted to print a label for a plot with the function name as the label; is there any way to determine the function name without hard coding it?

Comment: @tombom21 while answers in the linked topic suggest 'not without trickery' I believe it is a duplicate. Let me know if you disagree.

Comment: You might want to see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68823) too.