# Use Map with OptionValue

Tags: options, map, optional-arguments

Trying to map `OptionValue` to a list of option names doesn't work.

```
options = {opt1, opt2, opt3};
Options[f] = # -> True & /@ options;
f[x_, o:OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue /@ options;
f[x_] := f[x, Sequence@{}];
```

Executing

```
f[1, opt1 -> False]
```

gives the result

```
{OptionValue[opt1], OptionValue[opt2], OptionValue[opt3]}
```

instead of the expected

```
{False, True, True}
```

Why does this happen with `OptionValue` and can it be fixed?

Comment: Use `f[x_, o : OptionsPattern[]] := Evaluate[OptionValue /@ options];` instead

Comment: @belisarius The problem with this is that the r.h.s. will evaluate immediately.

Comment: Here is the fix: `f[x_, o : OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[#] & /@ options;`. For an explanation, read [this discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18674/evaluation-of-optionvalue).

Comment: In fact, this is an exact duplicate of that one, so I am voting to close...

Comment: @rm-rf Well, that was fast ...

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I guess we both found the duplicate at the same time :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin yeah, Options seem misleadingly simple :)

Comment: @rm-rf And apparently, commented at the same time too. Fastest gun in the West :)

Comment: @belisarius Oh yes :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I knew _exactly_ what to look for — all I did was search for `user:81 "OptionValue" magical` as soon as I saw the title :)

Comment: @rm-rf Me too - I looked for "evaluation of OptionValue" - I remembered the exact name of the question. It took me some time though to realize that that was the exact dupe.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Memoizing question names?

Comment: @belisarius Been doing that from the start, buddy :) Actually, my memory has some peculiar property that I remember a lot of background details like names of some supporting characters in second-rate movies for which I may not even remember much else. I often wish to clean up lots of garbage that I keep somehow - and the question names are by far not the worst of these things.

Comment: @belisarius In fact, remembering my past posts on SE, SO and MathGroup is perhaps a single most constructive use of this property I have, which somehow allows me to live in peace with this.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Try to find a good translation of this story:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funes_the_Memorious.  (the plot summary in Wikipedia is a shame)

Comment: @belisarius Well, yes, this sounds somewhat similar. Will look for it when I get some time. I've read other things from Borges, but not this one.