# Automating constructor definitions (OptionValue eval time)?

Tags: associations

I'm settling in on a programming pattern for "constructors." I can illustrate the pattern with the following example, which defines a constructor `newBar` for "objects"-as-Associations of type `bar`:

```
ClearAll[bar, newBar];
Options[newBar] = {"a" -> 42, "b" -> 43};
newBar[OptionsPattern[]] := <|"a" -> OptionValue["a"], "b" -> OptionValue["b"]|>

?? newBar
```

> ```
> Global`newBar
> newBar[OptionsPattern[]]:=Association[a->OptionValue[a],b->OptionValue[b]]
> Options[newBar]={a->42,b->43}
> ```

```
 newBar[]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 42, "b" -> 43|>
> ```

```
 newBar["b" -> 117]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 42, "b" -> 117|>
> ```

This does a nice job of supplying default values. The only downside is that there is LOTS of repitition in the boilerplate, and I'd like to abstract that out. Here's an almost-working attempt:

```
ClearAll[capitalize];
capitalize[string_String] :=
  With[{chars = Characters[string]},
   StringJoin[Prepend[Rest[chars], ToUpperCase[First[chars]]]]];

capitalize["foo"]
```

> ```
> "Foo"
> ```

```
ClearAll[camelback];
camelback[strings_List] :=
  StringJoin@Prepend[capitalize /@ Rest[strings], First[strings]];

Symbol@camelback[{"new", "foo"}]
```

> ```
> newFoo
> ```

```
ClearAll[constructor];
constructor[nym_Symbol, attributes_Association] :=
  With[{keys = Keys[attributes],
    values = Values[attributes],
    cNym = Symbol@camelback[{"new", ToString[nym]}]},
   ClearAll[cNym];
   Options[cNym] = Normal[attributes];
   cNym[OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Evaluate@Association[
      MapThread[Rule, {keys, OptionValue /@ keys}]]
   ];

constructor[foo, <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>]
?? newFoo
```

> ```
> Global`newFoo
> newFoo[OptionsPattern[]]:=<|a->OptionValue[a],b->OptionValue[b]|>
> Options[newFoo]={a->1,b->2}
> ```

So far, so good.  It looks very similar to the `bar` example. The most notable difference is the `<|...|>` notation instead of the call to `Association`, and that seems to be the clue, but I can't interpret the clue.  In any event, it doesn't work, presumably because `OptionValue` doesn't get evaluated at the right time.

```
newFoo["a" -> 42]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> OptionValue["a"], "b" -> OptionValue["b"]|>
> ```

Any advice?

Comment: Don't have much time to test now, but it should work when you change `OptionValue` to `(OptionValue[#]&)`, and has indeed to do with how / when `OptionValue` is evaluated. There has been a discussion on that, I will try to find a link.

Comment: Ok, [here it is](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18674/evaluation-of-optionvalue). Not sure whether or not your question is a dupe of that, would need to study it closer to tell.

Comment: Yup, changed `Evaluate@Association[MapThread[Rule, {keys, OptionValue /@ keys}]]` to `Association[MapThread[Rule, {keys, OptionValue[#]&/@ keys}]]` and it works :)  Promote to an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks much!

Comment: I actually think this is a dupe of that link, so I'd better vote to close. It's probably still worth to keep this question, perhaps the title could be changed a bit to reflect that the actual problem is in `OptionValue`.

Comment: ok, concur. I changed the title & vote to close.