# Why doesn't OptionValue cooperate with Map?

Tags: function-construction, optional-arguments

Consider the following definition:

```
Options[f] = {a -> 1, b -> 2}
f[x_,OptionsPattern[]] := {x,OptionValue/@{a,b}}
```

I thought that doing something like `f[4]` would produce `{4,{1,2}}` but it doesn't. Instead, evaluating `f[4]` returns `{4, {OptionValue[a], OptionValue[b]}}`.

Is there a way to make `OptionValue/@{a,b}` produce `{1, 2}`? Is there a better way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: There is likely some special evaluation at play here, since `{x, {OptionValue[a], OptionValue[b]}}` works.

Comment: @J.M. the only member of `Attributes[OptionValue]` is `Protected`...

Comment: it might be that `OptionValue[{a,b}]` works...

Comment: Note that `f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := {x, OptionValue[f, #] & /@ {a, b}}` allows `f[4]` to produce `{4, {1, 2} }`.

Comment: @jjc385; dully noted; edited Q

Comment: which one is 'proper'? "@jjc385"'s comment or the answer by "@Carl Woll"

Comment: I understand your point. A relevant question is why does `OptionValue[a]` work inside the definition of `f` without the need of `OptionValue[f,a]`-no need 'explaining' that we are interested in `f``'s option `a`?

Comment: See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18676/11035), especially the second paragraph, which suggests that `OptionValue` is able to figure out which function it appears in only when it's given explicit arguments in the function definition (before any evaluation occurs).  Actually, it turns out even `f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := {x, OptionValue[#] & /@ {a, b}}` works.

Comment: I have marked this question as *already has an answer* -- please review the linked post, and if you feel that it does not address your question edit yours to specifically describe how your question or needs differ.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm good, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
Options[f] = {a -> 1, b -> 2};
f[x_,OptionsPattern[]] := {x, OptionValue[{a,b}]}
```

Then:

```
f[4]
```

> {4, {1, 2}}