# Refer to OptionValue externally without a specific function name

Tags: functions, evaluation, options, hold

I want to refer to the actual option values of a function `f` outside of `f`, using `OptionValue`. Since I would use the same reference in different function `f`, `g`, etc., each resolving to its own actual option values, I do not want to specify the function name `f` in the external `OptionValue` call.

`OptionValue["opt"]` is not resolved to `OptionValue[f, "opt"]` inside `f`. Can I circumvent this without explicitly stating `OptionValue[f, "opt"]` in the external `assoc`? BTW, that wont' work either, returning the default 1 instead of 2.

```
ClearAll[f];
Options[f] = {"opt" -> 1};
f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := {
     OptionValue["opt"],     (* This is evaluated correctly *)
     x["Option"],            (* This is not resolved correctly *)
     Evaluate[x["Option"]]   (* This is not resolved correctly *)
  };

assoc = <|"Option" :> OptionValue["opt"]|>

f[assoc, "opt" -> 2]
```

Output:

```
{2, OptionValue["opt"], OptionValue["opt"]}
```

My expected result would be `{2, 1, 1}`, though I understand that the special nature of `OptionValue` prevents the kernel to resolve `OptionValue["opt"]` to `OptionValue[f, "opt"]` at the time it is first encountered.

Comment: If you look at [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18676/81), you will see that `OptionValue` is a magic head, which gets expanded to 3 - argument form before the r.h.s. of a function is evaluated. Which would mean that you can't accomplish directly what you are after - of course unless you use the 3-arg form of `OptionValue` directly. But, what is the actual need / problem? It looks like you would like to hide one option behind some other, such that both work, but only one is exposed / documented. If that is the case, I can suggest a way which I've used in such cases.

Comment: Thanks @Leonid for the explanation. I have a set of functions, like `f1`, `f2`, ..., which use roughly the same set of options, but with different values. I want to set up a global association `assoc` that can be used by any of the `f_i`, and references to options in `assoc` would magically be resolved to the actual option values of the `f_i` that uses it. The point is, that `assoc` is the one my clients should interact with (define), and not the `f_i`, so I want to make option-reference as trivial as possible, without introducing global symbols for all option values. Does it clarify my aim?

Comment: It does, but it is not an easy task. If I get some ideas, I will get back here.

Comment: @Leonid I appreciate your effort. I want to add, that whatever is used ultimately, it has to be domestic in the sense that I cannot expect the user to use anything more obscure than `OptionValue` to define parts of `assoc` (which holds more key-value pairs in reality). Moreover, I have nested options...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can (ab)use the automatic expansion of `OptionValue` into its three-argument-form, which works even inside rules:

```
Options[func] = {"opt" -> None};
{func["opt" -> 1], func[]} /. func[OptionsPattern[]] :> OptionValue["opt"]
(* {1, None} *)
```

Now, for your example: First, we define `iExpandOptionValue` that expands `OptionValue` into a list of expressions using the trick above.

```
Attributes[iExpandOptionValue] = {HoldAll};
iExpandOptionValue[OptionValue[head_, opts_, __], vars___] :=
 Hold[vars] /. <|args___|> :> <|args|> /. Hold[evars___] :> (
    Unevaluated@head[opts] /. HoldPattern@head[OptionsPattern[]] :> {evars}
    )
```

Note the `/. <|args___|> :> <|args|>` trick. This makes sure that associations inside `vars` are not initialized, [since otherwise the replacement doesn't work as expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148074/pattern-matching-association-in-rules).

Next, we define `ExpandOptionValue`. It is used as the right side of a definition, where the first argument specifies variables to "expand" using the function above, and the second argument is the expression to evaluate.

```
HoldPattern[lhs_ := ExpandOptionValue[{vars___}, rhs_]] ^:=
 Replace[
  {Hold[rhs], Quiet@Replace[Hold[vars], var_ :> Pattern[var, _], 1]},
  {Hold[rhs2_], Hold[pats___]} :> (
    lhs := iExpandOptionValue[OptionValue["dummy"], vars] /. {pats} :> rhs2
    )
  ]
```

We use a similar trick to above to extract the function on the left side using `OptionValue["dummy"]`, which we can then pass to `iExpandOptionValue`. After some more replacements, we are finally done. We can now use this on your example:

```
ClearAll[f];
Options[f] = {"opt" -> 1};
f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := ExpandOptionValue[{x},
   x["Option"]
   ];

assoc = <|"Option" :> OptionValue["opt"]|>;

f[assoc, "opt" -> 2]
(* 2 *)
```

To see a bit what's going on, we can look at the definition of `f`:

```
Definition@f
(* f[x$_,OptionsPattern[]]:=iExpandOptionValue[OptionValue[dummy],x$]/. {x_}:>x[Option]
 
Options[f]={opt->1} *)
```

Comment: +1. I planned to try something along similar lines,  but now I have no need to :)

Comment: This seems be doing what it should, thanks Lukas. Let me test it a bit more with production code, and accept if stable.