# OptionValue doesn't work if a local variable has the same name as the function itself

Tags: options, scoping

The following innocent-looking code results in error.

```
Options[add] = {number -> 1};
add[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{add},
   x + OptionValue[number]
];
add[1]
```

The error is

```
OptionValue::optnf: Option name number not found in defaults for add$2832.
```

What triggers the error is the fact that a local variable declared by `Module` has the same name as the function, `add`. (For simplicity, I've shown an example where this local variable isn't actually used in the code, but this doesn't make a difference.)

Is this a bug in Mathematica, or some known quirk of OptionValue[]?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like a variable capture, caused by the [macro-like expansion mechanism of `OptionValue`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18676/81) , which happens before the r.h.s. of the function gets evaluated.

### What happens

This can be seen if, for example, we wrap the r.h.s. of the function in `Hold`:

```
add[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := Hold[Module[{add}, x + OptionValue[number]]]
```

So that

```
add[1]

(* Hold[Module[{add$}, 1 + OptionValue[add$, {}, number]]]. *)
```

Here is my guess about what happens in which order:

- First, `OptionValue` expands. At this point we have

  ```
   Hold[Module[{add}, 1 + OptionValue[add, {}, number]]]
  ```

  Note that already at this point, the expansion of `OptionValue` effectively made the `add` inside `OptionValue[add, {}, number]` bind to the local `Module` variable.
- Then, `RuleDelayed` renames `add` to `add$`, trying to "protect" the local variable of `Module`
- Finally, in the original version without `Hold`, `Module` would evaluate, where at that point the local variable inside `Module` has shadowed the global `add` symbol in `OptionValue[add, {}, number]`.

So effectively the cavalier macro-style approach of `OptionValue` expansion mechanism, which pays no attention to lexical scoping, leads to a variable capture (the latter being also a general problem for macros and languages which support them).

### What could've happened

Since apparently the expansion mechanism of `OptionValue` is the very first one to fire in the process of rule application for rules containing `OptionsPattern` / `OptionValue`, that mechanism could've renamed the local `Module` (or other lexical scoping construct) variables before expanding the `OptionValue`.

That would lead, after `OptionValue` expansion, to something like

```
Module[{add$}, 1 + OptionValue[add, {}, number]
```

and things would've worked then as expected.

### But is the current behavior incorrect?

The real problem with this code, to me at least, is that there is no way to refer to the longer form of `OptionValue` within the `Module`: anyone who would attempt to do that, would effectively manually perform the same expansion, as done automatically for short form of `OptionValue`, and would end up with

```
add[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{add}, x + OptionValue[add, {}, number]]
```

So, while the behavior of `OptionValue` expansion mechanism could perhaps have been smarter - as mentioned above, this problem with 3-arg form of `OptionValue` shows that at least in part, this is a problem of how the code is written, since this longer form explicitly shows that the local variable shadows the global symbol, and there is no way one could refer to the global symbol without restructuring the code.

From this viewpoint, the behavior of single-argument `OptionValue` is actually correct.

### So is this a bug, and what to do about it

I tend to think that this is not a bug, for reasons discussed in the previous section. I don't even think that the smarter behavior of single-argument `OptionValue` would've been a good thing, because it would bring about yet more magic: it would make possible to specify the short form of the `OptionValue` that would bind to the global symbol in the case of shadowing, but not the long form.

To avoid this behavior, simply don't create such collisions. Namely, don't use for variable names the name of the function being defined. It should not be that hard.